# Allow/prevent default event based on conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

We are trying to implement the following requirement: User clicks on a link, we now need to call a function and then (after let's say 2000ms) execute the default link event (which can be opening the next page, a mailto link or whatever).

We tried a lot similar to this approach:

HTML

```
<a class="link-elem" href="foo.html">Foo Bar</a>
```

Event Listener

```
$('.link-elem').on('click', function(event, fromFunction) {
    if (fromFunction) {
      // do the default event
      console.log('event triggered again with fromFunction = true');
    } else {
      // call function
      otherFunction(event, {foo: 'bar'});

      // prevent default behavior
      // (tried all combinations of these)
      // return false;
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

Other function

```
var otherFunction = function(event, otherArg) {
   // do function stuff

   setTimeout(function() {
     // trigger event again with fromFunction = true
     $(event.target).trigger(event.type, true);
   }, 2000);
};
```

JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kwh5tay8/

The result of this is that we see the console.log message but the actual event does not happen, a.k.a. the next page is not loaded.

We cannot read the href attribute and do something like `window.location` as we cannot rely on the event being a simple link.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `otherArg`? You haven't defined it.

Comment: It's an object used in otherFunction, I added it for clarification.

Comment: The next page that is supposed to load, is it being linked as with an anchor tag, or have you defined another event listener for loading it ?

Comment: I am not sure I understood. If you want the default behavior to happen, why are you using event.preventDefault() ? I got rid of it and it worked

Comment: First, we need to prevent the default behaviour (e.g. opening a new page) because we need to give 2000ms time to otherFunction() to do something. Then after 2000ms we don't care anymore and need the default event to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is, you dispatch the event but you don't execute anything,
i prepared a sample js file you can use like that.

```
                var operation = "";

                $('.link-elem').on('click', function(event, fromFunction) {
                    if (fromFunction) {
                      // do the default event
                      callRequiredFunc();
                    } else {
                      // call function
                      otherFunction(event, { type : 'link', link: 'http://google.com'});

                      // prevent default behavior
                      // (tried all combinations of these)
                      // return false;
                      event.preventDefault();
                      event.stopPropagation();
                      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }
                });

                var otherFunction = function(event, otherArg) {
                   // do function stuff
                 operation = otherArg
                   setTimeout(function() {
                     // trigger event again with fromFunction = true
                     $(event.target).trigger(event.type, true);
                   }, 2000);
                };

                var callRequiredFunc = function(event){
                        switch(operation.type){
                            case "mail":
                                $(location).attr('href', 'mailto:?subject='
                             + encodeURIComponent("This is my subject")
                             + "&body=" 
                             + encodeURIComponent("This is my body")
                                 );
                            break;
                            case "link":
                                window.location.href = operation.link
                            break;
                            case "whatever":
                            break;
                            default:
                            break;
                        }
                }
```